# Unable to vertically align div using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here's my basic HTML:

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-4 center-block main-text center-text marg-small boxed">
                <div class="random">Some Text</div>  
                    <div class="col-lg-6 marg-small ">
                    <div  id="pick_channel" class="boxed orange">
                    <div class="square vertical">Channel</div>
                    </div>
                      <div id="pick_objective" class="boxed orange">
                      <div class="square vertical">Objective</div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
.boxed{
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap:nowrap;
align-items: center;
}

.square {
height:100px;
width:100%;
display:flex;
align-self:center;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.vertical{
}
```

I'm trying to end up with the `id`s `pick_channel` and `pick_objective` as rectangles with the text "Channel" and "Objective" vertically and horizontally centered with their respective `divs`. I've tried a bunch of combinations, but can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```css
.boxed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}
.square {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  /* display: flex; */
  /* align-self: center; */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-lg-4 center-block main-text center-text marg-small boxed">
    <div class="random">Some Text</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 marg-small ">
      <div id="pick_channel" class="boxed orange">
        <div class="square vertical">Channel</div>
      </div>
      <div id="pick_objective" class="boxed orange">
        <div class="square vertical">Objective</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```css
.boxed {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.square {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.orange {
  background: orange;
}
.center_content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 center_content">
  <div class="col-lg-6 marg-small ">
    <div id="pick_channel" class="boxed orange">
      <div class="square vertical">Channel</div>
    </div>
    <div id="pick_objective" class="boxed orange">
      <div class="square vertical">Objective</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is almost perfect. How do I center align the boxes within my `col-lg-4` div "above" all of this?

Comment: ok i edited it it looks weird now but with the bootstrap classes it should work